# Add header to UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I created the `UIPickerView` with 4 components. 
 
Can I add the header title for each component in that `UIPickerView`?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 8):

**Swift** version, based on @greentor's answer with some improvements:

```
var labelTexts = ["Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes"]

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let labelWidth = itemPicker.frame.width / CGFloat(itemPicker.numberOfComponents)

    for index in 0..<labelTexts.count {
        let label: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(itemPicker.frame.origin.x + labelWidth * CGFloat(index), 0, labelWidth, 20))
        label.text = labelTexts[index]
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        itemPicker.addSubview(label)
    }
```

[image: sample UIPickerView inside a popover on iPhone in Portrait orientation]
[image: sample UIPickerView inside a popover on iPhone in Landscape orientation]

Note that this might work incorrectly if called in ViewWillAppear or earlier because the UIPickerView won't know its frame dimensions at that point yet.

Answer (score 5):

One other technique I use from time to time is the make the header the first row in each column:

[image]

You need to increment the number of rows of course..

Comment: This isn't a good solution because when you scroll the top row goes away

Comment: And if default row is not in the first few, user won't even see it

Comment: I did say from time to time. It worked well for my use case.

Comment: Though this is good to keep in mind for "prefer not to say", "select city", etc

Answer (score 4):

I show 3 components and then use a UIView to show a title (UILabel) centred above each component (you can easily amend this for more or fewer components):

```
-(void)labelForDays
{
    NSString *strDay = @"Days";
    float lblWidth = self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.size.width / self.pickerDayHourMin.numberOfComponents;
    float lblXposition = self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.origin.x;
    float lblYposition = (self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.origin.y);

    UILabel *lblDay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lblXposition,
                                                                lblYposition,
                                                                lblWidth,
                                                                20)];
    [lblDay setText:strDay];
    [lblDay setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    [self.view addSubview:lblDay];
}
```

Then a label for 2nd component

```
-(void)labelForHours
{
    NSString *strHours = @"Hours";
    float lblWidth = self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.size.width / self.pickerDayHourMin.numberOfComponents;
    float lblXposition = self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.origin.x;
    float lblYposition = (self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.origin.y);

    UILabel *lblHours;
    if (self.pickerDayHourMin.numberOfComponents ==3)
    {
        lblHours = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((lblXposition + lblWidth),
                                                                    lblYposition,
                                                                    lblWidth,
                                                                    20)];
    }


    [lblHours setText:strHours];
    [lblHours setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    [self.view addSubview:lblHours];
}
```

and finally a label centred above the 3rd component

```
-(void)labelForMinutes
{
    NSString *strMinute = @"Minutes";
    float lblWidth = self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.size.width / self.pickerDayHourMin.numberOfComponents;
    float lblXposition = self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.origin.x;
    float lblYposition = (self.pickerDayHourMin.frame.origin.y);

    UILabel *lblMinute;
    if (self.pickerDayHourMin.numberOfComponents ==3)
    {
        lblMinute = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((lblXposition + lblWidth + lblWidth),
                                                           lblYposition,
                                                           lblWidth,
                                                           20)];
    }


    [lblMinute setText:strMinute];
    [lblMinute setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    [self.view addSubview:lblMinute];
}
```

Comment: this works and very controllable. enough for such trivial use case.
thanks @greentor

Answer (score 3):

You can use UIlabel above the UIPicker view,that works well